# Getting the x and y position of a range handle

Tags: html, range

I need to follow the range handle of a series as sliders as shown with a small div with text as shown below:

[image]

Is there a simple way to capture the handle's xy position in relation to the window? I have read a number of questions on this and I recognise that you can find the offset in realtion to the parent container but this seems to over complicate the matter.

For example I am trying this method: Get the x y postion of the slider's left-top corner in relation to the page and positioning the div accordingly. This method has potential to work but setting the style.left and style.top is relative to the window and not the page (still working on that). Any ideas?

```
function displayText(e) {
    var sliderValue=e.value;
    
    var sliderX = e.getBoundingClientRect().left; 
    var sliderY = e.getBoundingClientRect().top; 
    
    sliderX = sliderX + distance to handle (calculated from sliderValue)

    document.getElementById('sliderText').style.left = sliderX + 'px';
    document.getElementById('sliderText').style.top = sliderY + 'px';

}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you provide some sample code please

Comment: @StrayAnt I have made an edit to give you an idea of my current thinking but there remain issues as explained. I have tried other methods too such as following the x pos of the mouse which worked but was problematic if the mouse moved to fast. If I knew how to reference the slider handle (not just the slider) then maybe there is a simple solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it a code are you looking for?

```js
let range = document.querySelector('.range input');
let hint = document.querySelector('.range span');

hint.style.top = range.offsetHeight + 'px';

var thumbnWidth = 8;

let offset = range.clientWidth / (parseInt(range.max) - parseInt(range.min));
let updatePosition = () => {
  hint.innerHTML = range.value;
  hint.style.left = ((range.valueAsNumber - parseInt(range.min)) * offset - hint.offsetWidth / 2 - (range.valueAsNumber / parseInt(range.max) - parseInt(range.min) - 0.5) * thumbnWidth) + 'px'; 
  
};

updatePosition();
range.addEventListener('input', updatePosition);
```

```css
.range {
  position: relative; 
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.range span {
  position: absolute; 
  color: red; 
  border: 1px solid blue; 
}

.range input {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="range">
  <span></span>
  <input type="range" max="1000" min="0"> 
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you but I think not. Firstly you will notice the 'hint' does not sit perfectly over the handle - too left on the left and then too right on the right (mentioned in a number of questions I found in SO). But the main issue is I may have anywhere from 1 to 15 - not just one - which complicates things a little.

Comment: The 'hint' does not sit perfectly over the handle because the width of the thumb. I didn't add the thumb width because you was looking for "simple way". I updated my code in the answer.

Comment: Thanks - very helpful and appreciate the time you put into this.